# Sort a list of elements based on string value in element

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of arrays that have a value called status. I want to sort these by placing the arrays with the "Active" status to the front of the list. This is to display the active elements first in a later function. Any good ideas how to sort and place the active "contracts" first?

```
IEnumerable<Contract> mappedContracts = MapContractsToContracts(contracts);
mappedContracts.OrderBy(x => x.Status == "Active");
return mappedContracts.ToList();
```

Comment: `OrderBy` returns a new `IEnumerable`, so `mappedContracts` is unaffected.

Comment: Post code, not images, I fixed it or you.

Comment: What does the `Contract` type and its properties look like, especially the `Status` one? What does some example input look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming `Status` is a `string` and other statuses are not alphabetically before `"Active"`.

```
IEnumerable<Contract> mappedContracts = MapContractsToContracts(contracts);
return mappedContracts
    .OrderBy(x => x.Status)
    .ToList();
```

For a more rugged approach, in `MapContractsToContracts` you could convert the status string to an `Enum` or custom type that had its own implementation of `IComparable`. In that way, you could define the precedence and order of statuses and verify that the data from the API met your expectations.

Comment: Presuming no other statuses are alphabetically before "Active" is a fragile approach. If "Active" contracts need to come first, that should be explicit e.g. `x => x.Status == "Active" ? 0 : 1`

Comment: This is a good poin Johnathan. Though unlikely, this status is bound to an external api source, and if there comes changes to the wording of the the other statuses it might sort wrongly.

Comment: @Maffe Yep. Why risk it? Be explicit.

Comment: But what is the purpose of the ? 0 : 1 statement? :)

Comment: If `x.Status == "Active"` then it will order using the value 0 or else it will order using 1. Technically you could do `.OrderBy(x => x.Status != "Active")` because `false` < `true`, but the ternary is more readable IMO.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay whilst what you suggest is more robust for this specific scenario, what about sorting the other statuses?

Comment: @Jodrell That isn't a requirement according to the opening post, and an alphabetical sort would unlikely to correct anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jodrell's answer is correct for your specific scenario, I think
a good idea to make it a bit more general is to use an `enum` instead of `string` for the status property.

```
public enum Status
    {
        Active = 0,
        Deactive = 1,
    }
```

Then you should change your model:

```
public class Contract 
{
   ...

   public Status Status {get; set;}

   ...
}
```

Then you can use the below query, and be sure that contracts with `Active` status will always come first.

```
IEnumerable<Contract> mappedContracts = MapContractsToContracts(contracts);
return mappedContracts
    .OrderBy(x => x.Status)
    .ToList();
```

Good Luck.